# Problem from Zorich's book

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Choose real numbers $a$ and $b$ so that the function $f(x)=\cos x - \dfrac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}$ is an infinitesimal of highest possible order as $x\to 0$.

**My solution:** Actually this problem is not so difficult and I guess that I've almost solved it. We'll split the solution into some cases:

1. If $b=0$ and using Taylor's series one can write $f(x)=x^2(-1/2-a)+o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$.

So we see that if $a=-1/2$ then $f(x)=o(x^3)$. If $a\neq -1/2$ then $f(x)=o(x)$ as $x\to 0$.

2. Suppose that $b\neq 0$ then again using Taylor's series one can derive that $$f(x)=\cos x-(1+ax^2)(1+bx^2)^{-1}=x^2\left(-\frac{1}{2}-a+b\right)+x^4\left(\frac{1}{24}-b^2+ab\right)+x^6\left(-\frac{1}{720}-ab^2+b^3\right)+o(x^7).$$

One can show that if $a=-\dfrac{5}{12}$ and $b=\dfrac{1}{12}$ then $f(x)=o(x^5)$ as $x\to 0$.

**Definition:** If $f=o(g)$ and g is itself infinitesimal as $x\to 0$, we say that $f$ is an infinitesimal of higher order than $g$ as $x\to 0$.

**Question:** Can anyone explain in details which one has the highest possible order? I guess it should be in the case when $a=-\dfrac{5}{12}$ and $b=\dfrac{1}{12}$ but cannot explain it in a rigorous way. If someone can explain it in a great detail that would be awesome!

Comment: Does Zorich really use the language of "infinitesimal"? I find that rather troubling in a modern mathematics text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether $b = 0$ or not, we can always write $$f(x) = \cos(x)  - (1 + ax^2)(1 - bx^2 + b^2 x^4 - b^3 x^6 + \dots)$$ which leads to $$f(x) = (-a + b - 1/2)x^2 + (ab - b^2 + 1/24)x^4 + (-ab^2 + b^3 - 1/720)x^6 + \dots$$

Therefore for $a = -5/12$ and $b = 1/12$, we have $f(x) = 1/480 x^6 + \dots$ which has order of vanishing $6$.

On the other hand, if $f$ has order $\geq 6$, then we must have $−a+b−1/2 = 0$ and $ab−b^2+1/24 = 0$. It is easy to solve from these two equations that $a = -5/12$ and $b = 1/12$ is the only possibility.

Comment: I was thinking in a bit different way: for one pair of $(a,b)$ we get function $f_1$ so that $f_1=o(x), x\to 0$ and for other pair of $(a',b')$ we have the function $f_2$ so that $f_2=o(x^5), x\to 0$. In order to show that pair $(a',b')$ gives the highest order we need to show that $f_2=o(f_1), x\to 0$. Right? I am referring to the definition which I have provided in my post. Do I have correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, but if e.g. $f_1 = x^2 + x^3 + \dots$, then you not only know that $f_1 = o(x)$, but also know that $f_1 = \Theta(x^2)$, i.e. there exist positive real numbers $c, d$ such that $c|x|^2 < |f_1(x)| < d|x|^2$ for sufficiently small $x$. Thus if $f_1$ has order $2$ and $f_2$ has order $6$, then we must have $f_2 = o(f_1)$, as $|x|^6$ approaches $0$ faster than $|x|^2$.

Comment: I am still confused with your reasoning. I began to study them quite recently and I cannot catch your reasoning.

Comment: If you can give more details I would be happy to appreciate your answer!

Comment: Which part do you have problem with? The part that there exists $c, d$ such that $c|x|^2 < |f_1(x)| < d|x|^2$, or the part that $f_2 = o(f_1)$?

Comment: 1) The part where you derived that $f_1=\Theta(x^2)$ using that $f_1=o(x)$. 2) Also the part where you obtained that $f_2=o(f_1)$.

Comment: 1) If the Taylor series of $f_1$ starts with $x^2$, then we may write $f_1(x) = x^2 (1 + o(x))$ and thus when $x$ tends to $0$, the factor $1 + o(x)$ is bounded between two positive constants $c$ and $d$. 2) We have $|f_1(x)| > c|x|^2$ for some $c$ and $f_2(x) < d|x|^6$ for some $d$, thus $|f_2(x) / f_1(x)| < \frac d c |x|^4$ which tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $0$. This means $f_2(x) = o(f_1(x))$.

Comment: You consider $f_2(x)/f_1(x)$, right? In order to do that $f_1(x)$ should be nonzero, right?

Comment: Yes, but $f_1(x)$ must be nonzero for sufficiently small $x$, as $f_1(x) / x^2 = 1 + o(x)$ which tends to $1$.

Comment: Sorry but it is not so clear to me why $f_1(x)$ is nonzero. How it follows from $f_1(x)/x^2=1+o(x)$? It actually shows you that for small $x$ the value of $ f_1(x)/x^2$ is approximately $1$.

Comment: The symbol $o(x)$ means that it tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $0$. Therefore for sufficiently small $x$ we have $|o(x)| < 0.5$ and hence $f_1(x)/x^2 > 0.5$, or $f_1(x) > 0.5 x^2$. This in particular implies $f_1(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Let me digest all this. Can I ask you question if something is not clear? BTW, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can leave further comments on this question.

Comment: I think that I got the problem completely. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You've chosen the unique $a$ and $b$ to make the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^4$ vanish (I presume — I haven't checked) in the Taylor expansion. If you make any other choices, you'll have $f(x) = O(x^2)$ or $f(x)=O(x^4)$ instead. Getting $f(x)=O(x^6)$ is the optimal result.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in o(x^5)$, $x \to 0$, then $f(x)=\varepsilon(x) x^5 $, where $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \varepsilon(x) = 0$. Hence we can write representation $f(x)=\varepsilon(x) x^2 \cdot x^3= \varepsilon_1(x)\cdot x^3$, where  $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \varepsilon_1(x) = 0$, so we can say, that $f\in o(x^3)$ i.e. $o(x^5) \subset o(x^3)$. So, being in $o(x^5)$ means to be more higher order, then being in $o(x^3)$.

Comment: I was thinking in a bit different way: for one pair of $(a,b)$ we get function $f_1$ so that $f_1=o(x), x\to 0$ and for other pair of $(a',b')$ we have the function $f_2$ so that $f_2=o(x^5), x\to 0$. In order to show that pair $(a',b')$ gives the highest order we need to show that $f_2=o(f_1), x\to 0$. Right? I am referring to the definition which I have provided in my post. Do I have correct understanding?

Comment: I understand what you say, but let me suggest also following view: outgoing only from that $f_1 \in o(x^3)$ and $f_2 \in o(x^5)$ you cannot obtain $f_2\in o(f_1)$. Because $o(x^5) \subset o(x^3)$, then we can take both $f_1 ,f_2 $ in $o(x^5)$ and say, that one of them is in $o(x^3)$. Then you can take, for example $f_2(x)=x^6 \in o(x^5)$ and $f_1(x)=x^7 \in o(x^3)$ and find, that $f_2 \notin o(f_1)$. So, my view is that Zorich simply mean more high order of little-$o$.